# Snowflake in One Region, AWS bucket in another. Costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

Any Snowflake experts?
We have Snowflake Database in eu-west-2 and we have to read data from s3 buckets in us-west. Created snowpipes and SQS notification in s3 buckets. Will there be additional costs for reading from us-west-2 notification channel. Will it be cheaper to bring data to same region as Snowflake (s3 in eu-west-2) and then create a new snowpipe and read the data?

In Snowflake documentation, its mentioned data transfer cross regions incur egress charges in Azure & GCP but I'm not sure about AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external stage in Snowflake for pulling data into Snowflake, AWS will charge you directly for the egress of the data moving from one region to another region.  Snowflake will not charge you anything for that egress.  So, moving it manually and then ingesting will incur the same egress on AWS.  It'd be wasted effort.

Comment: As a note, last I checked data egress within AWS is not expensive.